# Grouping bounding boxes and Separating them - PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, ocr, arabic

So I have this output image of an arabic text, I want to group the small bounding boxes to the bigger ones, then I want to separate overlapping boxes

I have no clue how to start

[image]

This is an example of what I want to do

[image]